# How to return a rejected promise from a function that wants to do some async processing first

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have this wrapper around `fetch` that we use and in it I want to allow the consumer to call it like shown in this test.

```
  it("When we get a failure response Then we get rejected promise with error", done => {
    try {
      fetch.mockImplementation(
        mockFetch([
          {
            url: "/url",
            errorResponse: true,
            response: () => ({ error: "whoops" })
          }
        ])
      );
      store.getState.mockReturnValue({
        userContext: {}
      });

      const p = http.get("url", { sampleConfig: "sample" });

      setTimeout(() => {
        p.then(r => expect(r.result)).catch(e => {  
          try {
            expect(e.error).toBe("whoops");  <== CODE MAKES IT HERE
            done();
          } catch (e) {
            done.fail(e);
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      done.fail(e);
    }
  });
```

This is the code that is called by `http.get`

```
  return fetch(buildUrl(url), addJwtToken(config)).then(response => {
    if (response.headers) {
      setJwtTokenFromHeaderResponse(response.headers.get("Authorization"));
    }

    if (response.ok) {
      if (response.headers.map["content-type"].includes("stream")) {
        return response;
      }
      return response.json();
    }

    const unauthorized = 401;
    if (response.status === unauthorized) {
      // All else failed so redirect user to FMS to reauthenticate
      localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");
      return response.json().then(() => redirectToSignOut());
    }

    return response.json().then(r => Promise.reject(r));   <== THIS RIGHT HERE
  });
```

I don't want the caller to have to deal with doing

```
http.get('/foo').catch(r => r.json()).then(e => processError(e))
```

And instead want to handle resolving the `json()` error for them so they can just do this.

```
http.get('/foo').catch(processError)
```

I feel it's a reasonable design but maybe I'm missing something as node complains in my test by showing these warnings.

```
(node:6412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): [object Promise]
(node:6412) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:6412) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 2)
```

I can't figure out how to get it to stop spamming my tests with these warning or to figure out if there is an idiomatic way to accomplish my goals.

**Edit 1**
I updated the code to return the promise chain which was an unrelated bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of problems.

There will be an error if a response is processed with `response.json()` multiple times. `response.json()` should be called once:

```
if (response.status === unauthorized) {
  // All else failed so redirect user ot FMS to reauthenticate
  localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");
  response.json().then(() => redirectToSignOut());
}

return response.json().then(r => Promise.reject(r));
```

All promises should be chained. This

```
response.json().then(() => redirectToSignOut());
```

results in flawed control flow. It's unclear how it's expected to work but every promise should be returned from `then`.

Using `done` in tests is an antipattern with promises because its use results in human errors; all modern testing frameworks support promises. `try..catch` is inappropriate here because it cannot catch asynchronous errors from promises outside `async` function. `setTimeout` is inappropriate here, too.

It's also unclear why `r.result` should be a rejected promise because it isn't defined anywhere in the code.

With `async` it could be something like:

```
  it("When we get a failure response Then we get rejected promise with error", async () => {
      fetch.mockImplementation(
        mockFetch([
          {
            url: "/url",
            errorResponse: true,
            response: () => ({ error: "whoops" })
          }
        ])
      );
      store.getState.mockReturnValue({
        userContext: {}
      });

      const responsePromise = http.get("url", { sampleConfig: "sample" })
      await expect(responsePromise).rejects.toEqual({ error: whoops });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. You've covered a lot of things here so I'll go through them one by one.

1) We should be returning the promise chain in this code, `response.json().then(() => redirectToSignOut());` so thanks for point out that issue. However this is orthogonal to the issue we are having which a pretty minor situation of getting a warning message written to the console.

Comment: 2) I'm going to have to disagree with you when you saying using done in tests is an anti-pattern. We are writing E2E tests in a message based system, React Redux, and the only way have tests know when an error is raised by the code under tests is for us to replace our RaiseError action creator with a test dummy that calls done.fail(e) and passes the error allowing the tests to fail and get the error condition. I guess we could create a new promise in the test and return it passing reject to our test dummy but I don't really see value in one approach over the other.

Comment: A minor situation may result in make it not work as expected, and a warning is a sign that things went wrong. In your code it's possible that these two promises are executed together, `response.json().then(() => redirectToSignOut()); return response.json().then(r => Promise.reject(r));` I assume that they are mutually exclusive, it should be `return response.json().then(() => redirectToSignOut())`, shouldn't it? Using done in tests is an antipattern **with promises**.

Comment: 3) setTimeout is appropriate because it allows the test code to move to the next tick of the javascript event loop which will put it after the mocked API calls resolve. Without setTimeout you can't E2E test this feature.

Comment: After going through this point by point I've realized the discount between your advice and my approach is that you might not be used to doing E2E style tests with promises. Done is necessary here because the SUT will call `fetch` which we are mocking to return dummy data. We have to use setTimeout to move to the next tick and because of that we need a way to asynchronously let the test know we are done and the done method is provided for that purpose. Because we have to use done we can't use the async await approach you are recommending and this makes try\catch necessary.

Comment: Again thanks so much for taking the time but I was more looking for help with how to correctly return a failed promise chain from a function which in our code `return response.json().then(r => Promise.reject(r));` is causing a warning to get written to the console.

Comment: *setTimeout is appropriate because it allows the test code to move to the next tick* - this is the result of improper control flow. You don't have a promise to chain, so you needed to compensate race condition. As I said, it's a hack. It's not e2e vs unit. It's doing things properly vs improperly. I test with promises so I know what I'm talking about. You don't need `done` with promises (and therefore async..await) at all. Mocha supports promise returns from a test. It handles promise rejections. You don't need to call `done.fail` manually. The framework does this for you. That's what I mean.

Comment: You returned a promise correctly. You didn't handle errors properly. That's why I called `done` an antipattern when it's used with promises. It's prone to human mistakes. The warning occurs because a promise wasn't synchronously handled with `catch`. With your recent fixes, `p` is always a promise and setTimeout isn't needed, it could be `const p = http.get("url", { sampleConfig: "sample" }); p.then(r => expect(r.result)).catch(e => { ...`.

Comment: That's not correct or I'm not understanding your point. As I pointed out in the code above the code `<== CODE MAKES IT HERE` shows that the code does make it to the catch block so the issue is not that errors aren't being handled properly. The test is verifying the correct error behavior and it works\passes and this code has been manually tested. Our issue isn't the test, it's this line of code in the SUT that is causing a warning to happen `return response.json().then(r => Promise.reject(r));` I appreciate that you don't care for our testing approach but that's not the issue here.

Comment: First of all, it wasn't obvious from the code you posted that test really passes to `CODE MAKES IT HERE` point because of several problems I mentioned. It wouldn't pass this way, and then `(rejection id: 2): [object Promise]` could mean an error in the middle of http.get. But I glad that it passes.

Comment: The problem isn't testing approach but control flow. Again, there should be no setTimeout. It's harmful here. Rejected promise isn't handled properly because of it. Chaining promises to the point where no setTimeout is needed is the only correct way to do this test. I provided an example with async..await because it's straightforward but this can be done in plain ES6 as well. I assumed that setTimeout is there because there was no promise to chain at some point (hanging `response.json().then(() => redirectToSignOut())`), but now there's no such problem. It should work without `setTimeout(...)`

Comment: OK, I switched it to the async approach and the warning is no longer showed. I'll take it offline to figure out what the issue was with the way I was trying to test it. Thanks so much for your help and apologies for getting frustrated a bit.